How do nonlinear relationships affect casuality determination
Let's assume that I have only one independent variable and one dependent, and
I have a great model with minimal error which deals well with predicting.
Let's also assume that I do no know the true causal relationship between X and Y (which one is a cause and which is a result).
Case 1: model is linear:  y(x)= ax+b
In such case, I can both predict Y by X and vice versa
Case 2: model is nonlinear: y(x)= ax^2+bx+c
In such a case, I can only predict Y by X, but not X by Y since predicting X by Y will return 2 values
Question: Can the non-linearity as in "case 2" be a clue or indicator regarding the true causal relationship between X and Y? Or maybe can it indicate that while predicting X by Y there is some third hidden variable involved?
